# New mail alert in Thunderbird

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, thunderbird

I successfully configured Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1.15 in my Ubuntu 10.10.

I want some addon for popping up the new mails alerts, some thing like New Mail alert in a separate dialog box as we can set in outlook. I tried few addons (like New Mail Attention) but nothing worked. How can I make it work?